# WPF SQLite queries exception

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2015, sqlite

There are multiple related questions but none of them solved my problem.
I have a C# (WPF) Application which connects to a sqlite database. There are 2 model classes - Dealer and Order and 2 corresponding tables in the Database.

I am able to do CRUD operations in *Dealer* table but when trying to do the same in *Order* table, I get an Exception - *SQL Logic error or missing database*. I am pasting some of the related code:

**For Dealer**

```
using(SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(connectionString)) {
conn.Open();
using(SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(conn)) {
  cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Dealer(name, address, contact, note) VALUES (@Name, @Address, @Contact, @Note)";
  cmd.Prepare();
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", dealer.Name);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", dealer.Address);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Contact", dealer.Contact);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Note", dealer.Note);
  try {
   result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  }
```

**For Order**

```
using(SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(connectionString)) {
conn.Open();
using(SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(conn)) {
  cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Order(dealer_id, note) VALUES (@DealerId, @Note)";
  cmd.Prepare();
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DealerId", order.DealerId);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Note", order.Note);
  try {
   result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  }
```

I get the exception at `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` statement for Order.

I have cross verified column name spellings and tried `SELECT * FROM Order` which again returned the same exception.

I also tried `SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='Order';` from the **For Order** code above to check if table exists and it returned the correct table name.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ORDER` is a reserved keyword in SQLite so you should quote it, for example using **[** ... **]**:

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Order] (dealer_id, note) VALUES (@DealerId, @Note)";
```

There are four ways of quoting keywords in SQLite: https://sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html